# JavaScript: Stop animation on on Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need some help with the code below where I am trying to implement the "Stop Auto Progress" button.

When this button is clicked, it should cause the progress bar's incremental animation to stop, however I am not sure how to go about achieving this.

The code below is what I have so far - thanks in advance for any help:

```js
//Get Current Value of attributes
function getProgress() {
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("style","width:");
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML;
 }

//Set value of attributes
function setProgress(value) {
 document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("aria-valuenow",value);
 document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("style","width: " +value+ "%"); 
 document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = (value+ "%"); 
}

//Call get function assign a variable to this, When value is less than 100 value increases by 1. 
function increment() {
 var i = getProgress();
 if(i < 100){
  i++;
  setProgress(i); 
 }else{
  alert("Progress Complete!"); //Alert presents itself once the value reaches max value.
 }
}

//Decrease current value by -1.
function decrement() {
 var d = getProgress();
 setProgress(d - 1);
}

//Current value set back to 0.
function resetButton() {
 var r = getProgress();
 setProgress(r = 0);
}

//Auto complete value to max in this case max is 100 with Interval of 100.
function autoProgress() {
 var elem = document.getElementById("progressbar");
 var width = 0;
 var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
 function frame(){
  if(width == 100){
   clearInterval(id);
  }else{
   width++;
   elem.style.width = width + '%';
   elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
  }
 }
}

//Stop Auto complete value at current value when button is pressed.
function stopProgress(){
 //Need Help Here Please.
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
  
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
 
  </head>
  
  <body>
 <!-- Container -->
 <div class="container">
 
    <h1>This Process bar is animated using <br>JavaScript!</h1>
 <br>
 
 <!-- Div For Progress Bar -->
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"  style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progressbar" >0%</div>
 </div>
 
 <br>
 <!-- Buttons -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "increment()">Increment</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="resetButton()">Reset</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="decrement()">Decrement</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="autoProgress()">Start Auto Progress!</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="stopProgress()">Stop Auto Progress!</button>
 

 <!-- End of Container -->
 </div>
 
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have three return statements in your first function - only the first one will be run.

Comment: @Cathal, remove the double "on" from question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the progress animation, consider using [the `clearInterval()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) which allows you to stop the underlying interval that is driving your incremental animation.

The `clearInterval()` method takes an interval id (which is the value that the `setInterval()` functions returns), and causes the corresponding interval callback to stop running.

To integrate this with your code, you could pull the `var id` outside of the `autoProgress()` function, so that it is accessible to `stopProgress()` (where you would call `clearInterval()`). Also, as a safety measure, consider clearing any existing interval that is running on your `id` variable before starting a new one - the prevents multiple intervals running at once (which would likely mess up your progress animation).

See the `/*Update:*/` comments in the snippet below for more detail:

```js
//Get Current Value of attributes
function getProgress() {
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("style","width:");
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML;
 }

//Set value of attributes
function setProgress(value) {
 document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("aria-valuenow",value);
 document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("style","width: " +value+ "%"); 
 document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = (value+ "%"); 
}

//Call get function assign a variable to this, When value is less than 100 value increases by 1. 
function increment() {
 var i = getProgress();
 if(i < 100){
  i++;
  setProgress(i); 
 }else{
  alert("Progress Complete!"); //Alert presents itself once the value reaches max value.
 }
}

//Decrease current value by -1.
function decrement() {
 var d = getProgress();
 setProgress(d - 1);
}

//Current value set back to 0.
function resetButton() {
 var r = getProgress();
 setProgress(r = 0);
}

/* Update: Move id out side of autoProgress() */
var id;

//Auto complete value to max in this case max is 100 with Interval of 100.
function autoProgress() {
 var elem = document.getElementById("progressbar");
 var width = 0;
  /* Update: stop any previous interval if one exists, and set
  new interval */
  stopProgress();
 id = setInterval(frame, 100);
 function frame(){
  if(width == 100){
   clearInterval(id);
  }else{
   width++;
   elem.style.width = width + '%';
   elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
  }
 }
}

//Stop Auto complete value at current value when button is pressed.
function stopProgress(){
 /* Update: Stop id interval */
  clearInterval(id)
  id = ''
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
  
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
 
  </head>
  
  <body>
 <!-- Container -->
 <div class="container">
 
    <h1>This Process bar is animated using <br>JavaScript!</h1>
 <br>
 
 <!-- Div For Progress Bar -->
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"  style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progressbar" >0%</div>
 </div>
 
 <br>
 <!-- Buttons -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "increment()">Increment</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="resetButton()">Reset</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="decrement()">Decrement</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="autoProgress()">Start Auto Progress!</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="stopProgress()">Stop Auto Progress!</button>
 

 <!-- End of Container -->
 </div>
 
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're almost there.
To be able to stop an interval you need to store a reference in a variable.
That's what you're doing here already:

```
var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
```

Unfortunately this variable can just be seen inside your **autoProgress** function.
So declare it globally, outside of the function first

```
var id;
```

and call it like this inside the **autoProgress** function

```
id = setInterval(frame, 100);
```

Now you can simply stop the interval inside your **stopProgress** function by calling

```
clearInterval(id);
```